# Phantomjs load static content only in page.open

Tags: phantomjs, headless-browser

My case is to load static content only (the content we get using "wget") using phantomjs and then run some javascript to determine the "title" of the page. I dont need to load the whole page to know its title right?

Tried to use:

```
page.settings.resourceTimeout = 0;

page.settings.javascriptEnabled = false;

page.settings.loadImages = false;

page.settings.localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled = false;

page.settings.webSecurityEnabled = false;
```

but in this case my document.title is not working because my JS is disabled. Justified!

Is there a way to load only static content? Something like

`page.open(uri, static = true, ...`

Comment: Also, page.onLoadStarted is a contender for determining the title, but i want to do some analysis of some div nodes inside the body too. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10230) you can call `request.abort()` inside `page.onResourceRequested`. The example given there, to stop all css being loaded, is:

```
page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, request) {
    if ((/http:\/\/.+?.css/gi).test(requestData['url']) || requestData['Content-Type'] == 'text/css') {
       console.log('The url of the request is matching. Aborting: ' + requestData['url']);
       request.abort();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Devaroop I understood your question as you want to load the HTML content, but then not load any other resources, such as images, external Javascript, external CSS, fonts, etc. If so, that is the use-case that this feature was added for. (Abort all but the first request if you want to stop *everything*)

Comment: Agreed. This gives us only the privilege to filter css, js, any other calls that we can guess of. There might be other calls like php, java, etc which are impossible to determine. I wanted a call which mocks the "wget" behavior. Makes sense?

Comment: @Devaroop If you want to mock the wget behaviour, I have already given you that answer (except it is in a browser so *inline* JavaScript will still run and could modify the document body - but no further network requests will be done). By aborting all requests you stop anything else loading (including AJAX, which I guess is what you meant by "php, java, etc."?)
If this still doesn't answer the question, perhaps you can explain why you are not simply using wget? PhantomJS is a resource monster compared to wget.